# Ehanced For Loop to Standard Loop

Tags: java

I need some help with this enhanced for loop. I want to understand the coding for a standard loop and while loop, please. Thanks.

```
public static int average(int...numbers) {
    int total=0;
    for(int x:numbers)
        total+=x;
    return total/numbers.length;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: This is basically a for each loop for each element in numbers

Comment: What do you want to understand exactly? And what does the above have to do with a while loop?

Comment: The above loop is an enhanced for loop. I just want to understand how you would code it into a standard loop, and a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

In your example int...numbers is the same as "int[] numbers"

So the for loop would have to iterate over that array.

    
    `for(int i=0; i < numbers.length ; i++)
    {
       int x=numbers[i]
       ...
    }`
    

Would be a direct replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is equivalent to:

```
for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    int x = numbers[i];
    total+=x;
}
```

Each element is retrieved in order, and the code within the loop is executed for each element.

The first operation, `int i=0;` is executed upon entering the for loop, and only once.

The second operation, `i<numbers.length` is the condition which must be true for the for loop to continue. This can actually be any boolean expression. I do not advise making your boolean expression overly complicated, but be aware its possible. An example:

```
boolean continueSumming = true;
for(int i=0;i<numbers.length && continueSumming;i++){
    if(i>9)
        continueSumming=false;
}
```

This loop would only iterate for a maximum of 10 elements for example, as the `continueSumming` variable would be set to false at the 9th element (remember arrays are 0 indexed.)

The last operation, `i++` is also executed each iteration. Here it increments `i`.

`i` could be called the sentinel variable here as it controls when the loops execution ends. More bonus trivia for you.

A while loop is simpler, it repeats until some condition is no longer true.  This while loop is equivalent to your for loop.

```
int index = 0;
while(index < numbers.length) {
    total += numbers[index];
    index += 1;
}
```

Each element would be added to the total, and the loop would exit when index was greater than or equal to the length of the array. As each iteration of the while loop is incrementing the index by 1, it will be executed for each element.

While loops aren't *normally* used to iterate over arrays as `for` loop syntax is less verbose, and allows the sentinel variable `i` to fall out of scope, while the for loop syntax does not.

Comment: How so? I see no mistake. I believe you are mistaken @ZongZhengLi

Comment: Try running it then. Even if you didn't get the exception it would still produce the wrong result.

Comment: My mistake sir, you're correct. I apologize for my error, it has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is "What would be the difference between using a for loop or a while loop to find the average of an array of numbers?", here you go.

`for (x : y)` is a loop which allows you to operate on every object in the array `y` by using the reference `x`.

In your example, `int total=0;` is the total for the average calculation.

`for(int x:numbers)` allows you to run code on every integer in `numbers` through the reference variable of `x`

`total+=x;` adds the current number the loop is processing to the total, as an average calculator should

`total/numbers.length` divides the total by the amount of numbers (objects in the array `numbers`) to be returned; gives the average.

A while loop loops through until a boolean value, statement, or condition is false.

William Morrison shows you how it's done, by using an integer to show which object the loop is processing, and making a condition which checks whether the next-to-be-processed object even exists - whether its index, or the integer, is out of bounds of `numbers.length`.

`numbers[index]` is the same as `x` in the for loop's case.

A standard loop would take the same sort of conditions the while loop does.

```
for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index = index + 1) {
     total += x;
}
```

Hope this helps you understand looping more clearly!